# Run database migrations using Entity Framework core on application start

Tags: migration, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to configure `StartUp.cs` or `project.json` to run database migrations using Entity Framework Core on application start?

Now I have middleware that do this task, but it seems to make negative influence on performance because database is being checked each request received.

```
public class EntityFrameworkUpdateDatabaseMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public EntityFrameworkUpdateDatabaseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _next = next;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this in the config methods in your `Startup.cs`.  The simplest way is like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // add other services        
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    db.Database.Migrate();

    // configure other services
}
```

Comment: Finally, something that is really improved from EF 6

Comment: is it override tables on production server?

Comment: For EF core, if the database migration project is created as a seperate project, configure the dbcontext with MigrationsAssembly options will make it work.        
  `services.AddDbContext<SampleDbContext>(opt =>
               opt.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString,                                                       
           x => x.MigrationsAssembly("SampleApi.DbMigration")));`