# Automatic DB update when publishing to Azure ast.net MVC 6 EF7

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to execute the pending migrations automatic after publishing. I know there was an option for this in EF6.

Comment: One option is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282138/run-database-migrations-using-entity-framework-core-on-application-start

Comment: Do you publish to Azure from Visual Studio, or do you have a build environment that does the deployments? Or Git deployment?

Comment: I publish from VS2015 community.