# Entity Framework Core 1.0 code-first migrations using code?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In previous versions of Entity Framework code-first migrations could be controlled programmatically with the DbMigrator class (e.g. check for and apply available migrations). Does that class still exist somewhere or is there a functional replacement? I found a post on an early RC version that indicated a substitute but that too seems to be missing from Core 1.0. I can control my migrations through CLI without issue but I think an in-code solution for custom tooling scenarios is going to be needed.

Comment: For those coming to this question looking for something similar, but for ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0 and Entity Framework Core 1.0, see this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282138/run-database-migrations-using-entity-framework-core-on-application-start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functional replacement can be found in a few places, primarily in the API found in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations namespace.

Some places to look:

- [`IHistoryRepository.GetAppliedMigrations()`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Migrations/IHistoryRepository.cs)
- [`IMigrator.Migrate(string
  targetMigration)`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Migrations/IMigrator.cs)
  (which is the same as calling
  [`DbContext.Database.Migrate()`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs#L32-L33))
- [`IMigrationAssembly`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Migrations/IMigrationsAssembly.cs) to find current migrations

With the exception of `IMigrator.Migrate`, using these API usually means pulling the service out of [internal EF Core's service container.](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/internals/services.html) This is done by calling `.GetService<TService>()` on your dbcontext.

Example:

```
var migrator = context.GetService<IMigrator>().Migrate();
```

Comment: The GetService<T> method is not available to my context. I'm assuming it's an extension method? What dependent package and namespace contains that method?

Comment: It's in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure` namespace. You don't need an extra package.