# .net core ef migration testing - apply migrations using c# method

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I think that ef migrations must be tested.
As for me integration testing will be best solution.
Current solution is to apply migrations to in memory database, but problem is that i want to run down scripts of migration also.

Do yoy know how to apply migrations using c# code?

Comment: Yes it is same question. Thank you. I think that my question maybe removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core 1.0 code-first migrations using code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408213/entity-framework-core-1-0-code-first-migrations-using-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get your context and call

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Startup.cs Configure method, we run migrations like this (in .Net core 2.0):

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DataContext>().Database.Migrate();
            }
```

I am not sure how you can test this. Possibly backup and restore the live database to a test one, then setup your DataContext to point to the test and run the migration there?

Answer (score -1):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/38416891/2875452. I was able to find out how to migrate to a specific migration using ef core in c# code.

```cs
context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); // ensure db is deleted on starting
context.Database.Migrate(); // run migrations
context.GetService<IMigrator>().Migrate("0"); // 0 this will rollback all migrations, you can pass in the specific migration name here to go up or down to that migration
```

Using command line
`dotnet ef database update 0`