# How to change connection string on command line to update database on migration to a new database in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, multi-tenant, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core and EF Core Code First, I have a multi-tenant webapp. When I create a new tenant, I want to change connection string, add migration on it and then update.

From command line, add migration can't get connection string dinamically on tenant and so i haven't a valid connection string for create a new database in the first time the app starts with a new tenant.
Is there any solution for it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this? **Edit**: this is for EF 6.1

```
Update-Database –ConnectionString "Data Source=YourDatabaseServer; Initial Catalog=YourDatabase; Integrated Security=True;"
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved by inserting inside the DbContext constructor:

```
Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That's not a good solution.  Every time an instance of your DbContext is created it will perform this check.  You want to perform migrations once on startup.  See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38283080/5782634

Comment: Thank you, your solution is better than mine. The important is to create at least one migration for each context.