# Deploy EF Core SqlServer Database to Production Environment

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Have developed new ASP.NET Core 1.1 MVC web site using Entity Framework Core and MSSQL LocalDB Server. I am new to the Entity Framework world as this is my first EF project. My production environment hosting provider creates an empty MSSQL database and then I must update that with whatever schema is needed. So how do I update or migrate the development schema into the empty production database on production server?

Is there someone or some document that can guide me thru this process. It would be much appreciated.

Orgbrat

Comment: This answer should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/38283080/5782634

Answer (score 0):

Check con this MVA: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/implementing-entity-framework-with-mvc-8931?l=e2H2lDC3_8304984382

I would recommend going over the whole course but you can focus on "Managing the Database" - "Code First Migrations". Hope this helps.