# How to run sql script before the application launches in docker

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, docker, asp.net-core

I'm deploying the project with Asp.net Core, PostgreSql and Docker in Windows 10 (no PostgreSql installed). So I have to run sql script to update data before the application launches (for registering a singleton dependency injection).

The content of my Dockerfile as following:

```
# TODO use official docker image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1.0-sdk-projectjson

# Install .NET CLI dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        bzip2 \
        file \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        imagemagick \
        libbz2-dev \
        libc6-dev \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libdb-dev \
        libevent-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libgdbm-dev \
        libgeoip-dev \
        libglib2.0-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        libmagickcore-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        libmysqlclient-dev \
        libncurses-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libtool \
        libwebp-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libyaml-dev \
        make \
        patch \
        xz-utils \
        zlib1g-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"

# Copy files to app directory
COPY . /app

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Restore NuGet packages
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

# Build app
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

#dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
RUN ["dotnet", "ef", "migrations", "add", "InitialCreate"]
# Open up port
EXPOSE 5000

CMD chmod +x ./docker-start.sh
CMD bash ./docker-start.sh
```

And here is the content of docker-start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# How to apply migrations
dotnet ef database update

# I would like to run sql file at here"
psql -h postgres --username postgres -d POSTGRES_USER -a -f /app/static.sql    

# Start web app
echo "Starting web app"
dotnet run
```

How can I do that? Thanks advanced.

Comment: Does your script running command failed? What is the question?

Comment: You might find it easier to run your migrations in code.  See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38283080/5782634

Comment: yes @evgenyl I cant not run the script.

Comment: @Brad, I have to run the script before the app starting so i cant use the code for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a solution for this. I missed **postgresql-client**. We will be need to install **postgresql-client** as using **psql** to run the sql script from Dockerfile.

So Dockerfile should be changed:

```
# TODO use official docker image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1.0-sdk-projectjson

# Install .NET CLI dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        bzip2 \
        file \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        imagemagick \
        libbz2-dev \
        libc6-dev \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libdb-dev \
        libevent-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libgdbm-dev \
        libgeoip-dev \
        libglib2.0-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        libmagickcore-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        libmysqlclient-dev \
        libncurses-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libtool \
        libwebp-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libyaml-dev \
        make \
        patch \
        xz-utils \
        zlib1g-dev \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install netcat so that we can ping the database server until it
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y netcat \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
ENV DB_HOSTNAME="posgres"

# Copy files to app directory
COPY . /app

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Restore NuGet packages
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

# Build app
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

#dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
RUN ["dotnet", "ef", "migrations", "add", "InitialCreate"]
# Open up port
EXPOSE 5000

CMD chmod +x ./docker-start.sh
CMD bash ./docker-start.sh
```

Thanks.